# SAS Enterprise Guide Autoarrange Issue

Tags: sas

I use SAS EG version 7.1 (recently been upgraded from an older version) and from time to time it throws a hissy fit and the whole process flow decides to autoarrange itself causing endless grief. I always have the autoarrange functionality disabled, in case you were wondering. SAS technical helpdesk couldn't get to the bottom of the issue. Has anybody else experienced this issue and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

RaulV

Do you have your project scheduled on your machine? If so, sometimes the result of scheduler leads to saving the project back with changed arrangement. Consider changing VBS file that coordinates the SAS job to avoid saving the project back after the job is done.

When project is saved, the logs are saved within the project. If you disable the project saving in VBS file, you might need to save your logs outside of the EGP project which is not difficult with PROC PRINTTO.

Vasilij